# Error: "You need to call RxApp.ConfigureServiceLocator to set up service location"

Tags: c#, reactiveui

The following code provides the runtime error in the question title. Though, when I comment out the OneWayBind() call within the MainWindow constructor, the app runs without error. Any ideas?

**The Window**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.ContentItems, x => x.panelDemo.ItemsSource);
    }

    public MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (MainViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(MainViewModel), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (MainViewModel)value; }
    }
}
```

**The Class**

```
public class ContentItem
{
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**The ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    string _Directory;
    public string Directory
    {
        get { return _Directory; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.Directory, value); }
    }

    bool _IsBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _IsBusy; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.IsBusy, value); }
    }

    ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IList<ContentItem>> _ContentItems;
    public IList<ContentItem> ContentItems
    {
        get { return _ContentItems.Value; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenAny(x => x.Directory, x => x.Value)
            .Do(_ => IsBusy = true)
            .Select(GetImages)
            .Do(_ => IsBusy = false);
    }

    IObservable<IList<ContentItem>> GetImages(string directory)
    {
        return new DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles().ToList().ToObservable()
            .Select(x => new ContentItem
            {
                Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(x.FullName)),
                Name = x.Name
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Thank you so much! The only thing I wish of ReactiveUI 4.5.0 is that it have current WPF implementation samples! They're all six months or more outdated!

Comment: Do you have a reference to ReactiveUI.Xaml in your project?

Comment: Thank you, Paul. NuGet indicated that ReactiveUI.Xaml was installed and properly referenced. I corrected the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling ReactiveUI through NuGet.